# Excel Conditional Formatting, alternating groups of three columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

In columns A, B, and C, I have the original data.  In columns J, K, and L, the conditional formatting gives us Green for a match and Red for a mismatch.  I'd like to apply that same formatting to alternating groups such as P, Q, and R.  Then, in the in-between groups of columns, such as M, N, and O, I'd like the conditional formatting to provide a slightly bluer versions of green and red.

My question is whether this could be accomplished with a single set of rules applied to all cells, or how two sets of rules could be applied, or do I need a separate set of rules for each set of three columns?

Conditional Formatting Rules:
[image: Conditional Formatting Rules]

Spreadsheet with alternating groups of three columns:
[image: Spreadsheet with alternating groups of three columns]

Comment: What have you tried so far and what research have you done regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing as few conditional formatting rules as possible is the goal, it is always possible to write supporting formulas in other cells in an unused part of the workbook, so that for any cell you have a supporting cell somewhere else returning a 1, 2, 3, or 4 (corresponding to green, blueish-green, red, or blueish-red) that can be referenced in the conditional formatting rule.

However, this is probably less practical than just writing a set of rules for each of the 6 column comparisons you are making:

- Columns J, P, etc. are compared to column A (for red/green format)
- Columns K, Q, etc. are compared to column B (for red/green format)
- Columns L, R, etc. are compared to column C (for red/green format)
- Columns M, S, etc. are compared to column A (for bluer format)
- Columns N, T, etc. are compared to column B (for bluer format)
- Columns O, U, etc. are compared to column C (for bluer format)

Whether you repeat this across 1 set of 6 columns or many sets of 6 columns, you won't need any more rules--you can just expand the number of columns a given rule applies to.

[Conditional Formatting Rules to Compare Against Column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCifz.png)

The formula will take the form **cell value = $A1** (**cell value <> $A1** for mismatch), and can be set to apply to **=$J:$J,$P:$P** for red/green, and apply to **=$M:$M,$S:$S** for the bluish shades.

(If you wanted the pattern to repeat again in column V, you would just add column V after column P to the "Applies To" box).

[Conditional Formatting Rules to Compare Against Column B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjAPG.png)

[Conditional Formatting Rules to Compare Against Column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBAao.png)

Comment: Thank you.  I've spent days on this, but without knowing a tool (or a strategy) exists, there's no way to fruitfully search for a solution. You've given me a solid strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating 12 rules, two for each of the six column types.  I used an `AND()` for green results and an `OR()` for red results, in order to correctly color blank cells.

```
Green =AND(J4=$A4,J4<>"")
Red   =OR(J4<>$A4,J4="")
```

[image: Conditional Formatting Dialog]

[image: Spreadsheet with alternating three column groups]